# I Have a problem when insert data python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing to you because I cannot solve this:

I want to insert into a database with 2 fields: ID AND DATE.

and in python it throws me an error: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1.

thankss a lottt

My code:

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
     with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
     return result
```

def add_fecha(self):

```
        query = 'INSERT INTO base VALUES(NULL, ?)'
        parameters = "19-2-2022"

        self.run_query(query, parameters)
     
        self.get_fechas()
```

Answer (score 1):

The substitution parameters value must be a tuple (or some kind of iterable).  You're giving it a string, which IS an iterable, but it's going to try to use it one character at a time.

Simple fix:

```
        self.run_query(query, (parameters,))
```

Comment: hello tim i put your code and now python tell me this: File "d:\PYTHON\Control Asistencia\index.py", line 96, in add_fecha
    self.run_query(query, (parameters,))
  File "d:\PYTHON\Control Asistencia\index.py", line 69, in run_query
    result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: @JesusVitali is any other program using the same database file at the same time ?

Comment: yes that was the problem, thank you very much, its works!!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) are used as iterables. When you pass your date string directly, its
is also taken as iterable, therefore passing 9 parameters rather than a single date string.

You need to put your string in a tuple or a list to pass it all at once.

See the following example:

```py
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE t (id INT, date TEXT);")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, ?)", ["2022-06-20"])
    print(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM t").fetchall())
```

Comment: thank you, yes i will read all this for understand